# Mybatis, referenciar una clase desde otro projecto en el Mapper.xml

Tags: java, mybatis

Buenas a todos, estoy usando MyBatis y estoy teniendo un error de **ClassNotFound** en un resultMap en el cual tengo referenciada una clase de otro proyecto. Adjunto código a continuación:

-**Mapper.xml**: Aquí solo colocaré el resultMap, que es donde estoy teniendo problemas al ser el lugar en el que defino la clase del proyecto externo.

```
    <resultMap id="BaseResultMapGeneralConfig" type="classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="NUMERIC" property="id" />
    <result column="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <result column="value" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="value" />
    <result column="type" jdbcType="NUMERIC" property="type" />
  </resultMap>
```

En teoría, que yo sepa, con eso sería más que suficiente. Ahora bien, también he añadido en mi proyecto main, el proyecto del cual quiero hace referencia a la clase en la pestaña **Projects** del **Java Build Path** de mi proyecto main, y también he marcado el check del proyecto externo en **Order and Export**.

-**La traza de error:**

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in com/iecisa/tecdoc/sirene/db/map/SireneConfigMapper.xml ### The error occurred while processing mapper_resultMap[BaseResultMapGeneralConfig] ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error inicializando SqlSession. Causa: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in com/iecisa/tecdoc/sirene/db/map/SireneConfigMapper.xml ### The error occurred while processing mapper_resultMap[BaseResultMapGeneralConfig] ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
Error creando SqlSession: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error inicializando SqlSession. Causa: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in com/iecisa/tecdoc/sirene/db/map/SireneConfigMapper.xml ### The error occurred while processing mapper_resultMap[BaseResultMapGeneralConfig] ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath:com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.common.types.GeneralConfig
```

He probado diferentes formas, así como poner la clase sin "classpath:", pero no encuentro la manera de resolver el problema.
¿Alguna idea? ¿He pasado algo por alto?
Toda ayuda es de agradecer.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el error. El problema estaba en que mi proyecto main es Maven y el externo no.
Al final solo tuve que añadirlo como .jar, agregarlo al pom.xml y compilar.
Con eso se me solucionó el error!